# Jupyter notebook Vs code failed to start Kernel

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[Hi All, I can't execute jupyter notebook code and I don't know why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQxfO.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to print a simple statement. Click the blue underlined text above and a picture should show up.

Comment: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;\kernel-v2-13448VBKgI35G04Bz.json']. It seems to be looking here but I have Anaconda installed at the user level. How do I change the Extension lookup? Or is this something else causeing my prob

Answer (score 0):

Please try installing jupyter in this conda environment.

```
conda install jupyter
```